# Is it possible to pattern match on a (nested) Vec in Rust?

Tags: vector, rust, pattern-matching

A library presents me with a deeply nested data structure that I would like to match on. It contains `Vec`s internally. I would like something like one of the commented out lines to work:

```rust
struct Foo {
    bar: Vec<bool>,
}

let foo = Foo {
    bar: vec![true, false],
};

match foo {
    // Foo{bar:[true,false]} => Ok(()), // expected an array or slice, found Vec<bool>
    // Foo{bar:&[true, false]} => Ok(()), // expected struct `Vec`, found reference
    // Foo{bar:vec![true,false]} => Ok(()), // Arbitrary expressions aren't allowed in patterns
    Foo { bar: v } => match v.as_slice() {
        [true, false] => Ok(()),
        _ => bail!("match failed!"),
    }, // Ugly when nesting deeply
    _ => bail!("match failed!"),
}
```

The match statement can be broken into smaller pieces that first do some dereferencing/unpacking on the value being matched, turning it into a slice first. I am currently doing this in my code, but it is quite ugly, and obscures the structure of the thing being destructured.

The issue is that `Vec` is in the standard library, not part of the language, but I'm still hoping there is some pattern matching magic that can get around this.

Comment: To be clear, when you speak of "nesting deeply", do you have Vecs within Vecs within Vecs?  Because that feels like a bit of an anti-pattern.  It ought to be possible to leverage Rust's type system in order to delegate the match operation at each level of "nesting"?

Comment: The structures in question are coming out of the https://docs.rs/msgpack_simple/1.0.2/msgpack_simple/ crate, which models maps using vectors of entries. The type schemas came from a python codebase that uses nested maps heavily on the serialized side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, pattern-matching vecs (let alone in-place) is not currently supported. Currently, Rust only supports a somewhat limited forms of [slice patterns](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2359-subslice-pattern-syntax.html), and even that is fairly recent (1.42).

You could use some of the other Rust facilities to make the code slightly terser but that's about it e.g. `if let` or [`matches!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.matches.html)

```rust
    match foo {
        Foo { bar: v } if matches!(v.as_slice(), [true, false]) => Ok(()),
        _ => bail!("match failed!"),
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `matches!`. Not sure if I'll use here but I'm sure I'll find places to use it. Know of any RFC's I could upvote? Not being able to match on core stdlib types like `Vec` and `String` really hurts pattern matching.