# Match an enum that takes a vector in one of its fields

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match an event to a start of a heading with `pulldown_cmark`.
Let's say I have this:

```rust
enum MyEvent<'a> {
    Start(MyTag<'a>),
    End(MyTag<'a>),
}

enum MyTag<'a> {
    Heading(SomeHeadingLevelEnum, Option<&'a str>, Vec<&'a str>,
    Paragraph,
}

fn main() {
    // Simplified the enums for the sake of the example
    let event = Start(Heading(Level::H1, None, vec![]));
}
```

How can I match the event to a type? Tried with:

```rust
fn main() {
    // ...
    match event {
        Start(Heading(H1, None, [])) => println!("a heading!"),
        _ => println!("yeah not a type I know for sure"),
    }
}
```

but got:

```
Start(Heading(H1, None, [])) => println!("a H1!")                                        
                        ^^ pattern cannot match with input type `Vec<&str>`
```

I tried with other approaches, as using `vec![]`, `&[&str]`, `Vec::new("")`, but got other errors as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to pattern match on a (nested) Vec in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67072873/is-it-possible-to-pattern-match-on-a-nested-vec-in-rust)

Comment: TL;DR: [Deref patterns](https://github.com/rust-lang/project-deref-patterns) will allow that, currently this is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an expression in a `match` expression like that, it takes a variable there instead, which it will populate with a successful match if one exists. If you want it only to succeed when the `Vec` is empty, then you can use a `match guard` to check it:

```rust
match event {
    Start(Heading(H1, None, v)) if v.is_empty() => println!("a heading!"),
    _ => println!("yeah not a type I know for sure"),
}
```

Side note: instead of having `&str` in your `enums` like that, you may want to use a `String`, so that you don't have to propagate those pesky lifetime annotations everywhere.

Comment: yeah that &'a str thing is what `pulldown_cmark` uses so it's kind of it's internal way of representing stuff. also thank you!

Comment: no problem, the pattern matching and destructuring was one of the most difficult parts for me to understand coming to Rust, too

Answer (score 2):

You can't match a `Vec` of specific length. As a pattern, `[]` matches an array of length zero, which is not the same as a `Vec`.

Instead, you can match the variable and add a guard for it being empty:

```
match event {
    Start(Heading(H1, None, lines)) if lines.is_empty() => println!("a heading!"),
    _ => println!("yeah not a type I know for sure"),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it do not work like that, you would have to match it and then use a guard in the match branch:

```rust
match &event {
    MyEvent::Start(MyTag::Heading(Heading::H1, None, v)) if v.is_empty() => println!("a heading!"),
    _ => println!("yeah not a type I know for sure"),
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=af4e484ead57e49384673a5cf60edd8b)